# What does "speaks to the mindset" mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english

I don't understand the following sentence.

"It speaks to the mindset that a lot of these channels have"

I'm really lost right now, i've tried googling it to no avail, if anyone could help out i would really appreciate it.

Comment: What are the _channels_? Radio/TV?

Comment: YouTube Channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means it addresses the way people are already thinking. Fits in with their style. So, hopefully it should be easy for the audience to relate to, understand, and appreciate it.

Their 'mindset' is their cultural, social, environmental, community way of currently perceiving things.

For example,

- 'in Victorian times, the mindset of teachers and educationalists was draconian and cruel towards children.'
- 'The current mindset in the medical industry favours non-invasive treatment'

'Speaks to' is an Americanism that I have mostly heard in business, and it means 'responds to'.

To give an example of the whole thing:

- 'our newly invented stick-on prosthetic ears *speak to the mindset* of today's doctors, who favour non-invasive treatments.'
- 'rap music *speaks to the mindset* of today's youth... and so we are going to use it in our advertising campaign'
- ‘TV shows about animals and pets *speak to the mindset* of the mostly young and very old viewers of these channels - so we aim to air our ’cats and dogs’ show there.’

Comment: So it's kind of like saying, what one is thinking, their mindset. Right?

Comment: Yes, it's like the landcape of what people are thinking, often, a group of people. I updated the question a bit. 

Comment: Awesommmeee! That makes me happy! 

Comment: For me, "speaks to" has more the connotation of "highlights" or "exemplifies".